# Validation on EditText is not working Correctly

Tags: java, android, validation

I have a **sign up** activity and trying to validate the fields on **SIGN UP BUTTON** Click. I'm using `setError()` method to show error message Its working **But** there is a problem Its working on the specific field which has focused at that time. What I want is It should check all the fields and validate message should appear at all the fields at once **OR** From Top to the end one by 1 if more than 1 fields are invalidate

What I have so far is 
**Code of SIGN UP BUTTON**

```
if (mSignUpBtn != null) {
            mSignUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override


           public void onClick(View arg0) {

                assert unameEditText != null;
                final String uName = unameEditText.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidName(uName)) {
                    unameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    unameEditText.setError("Invalid Username, Username must be A-Z,a-z,_,0-9 Can't contain Space");
                }
                assert emailEditText != null;
                final String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
                    unameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    emailEditText.setError("Invalid Email");
                }
                assert passEditText != null;
                final String pass = passEditText.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidPassword(pass)) {
                    unameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    passEditText.setError("Invalid Password");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Code of Validation methods**

```
private boolean isValidName(String uName) {
    String NAME_PATTERN = "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789_]*";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(NAME_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(uName);
    return matcher.matches();
}

// validating email id
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}

// validating password with retype password
private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    return ( pass.length() > 6);
}
```

Everything is fine except that it should validate all the fields by order **OR** by all at once rather than just the focused one

Here is image that shows if `USERNAME` Field is has spaces in it its showing error message but not showing anything on Email and Password fields because those are not at focus

[image]

What should I do to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: use this pattern 

`String regx = "^[\\p{L} .'-]+$";`

Comment: pattern is I think correct because when Email field is on focus it show error on that field if it has anti-pattern characters

Answer (score 1):

Try  this ;

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

         assert unameEditText != null;
         final String uName = unameEditText.getText().toString();
         assert emailEditText != null;
         final String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
         assert passEditText != null;
         final String pass = passEditText.getText().toString();
         if (!isValidName(uName)) {
             unameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             unameEditText.setError("Invalid Username, Username must be A-Z,a-z,_,0-9 Can't contain Space");
         }else if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
             unameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             emailEditText.setError("Invalid Email");
         }else if (!isValidPassword(pass)) {
             unameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             passEditText.setError("Invalid Password");
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Take a boolean flag and check it to maintain order**, as below first it will check username than email and than pass

```
boolean isSave = true;

if (mSignUpBtn != null) {
            mSignUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                assert unameEditText != null;
                final String uName = unameEditText.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidName(uName)) {
                    unameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    unameEditText.setError("Invalid Username, Username must be A-Z,a-z,_,0-9 Can't contain Space");
                    isSave = false;
                }
                assert emailEditText != null;
                final String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
                if (isSave && !isValidEmail(email)) {
                    unameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    emailEditText.setError("Invalid Email");
                    isSave = false;
                }
                assert passEditText != null;
                final String pass = passEditText.getText().toString();
                if (isSave && !isValidPassword(pass)) {
                    unameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    passEditText.setError("Invalid Password");
                    isSave = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Check edited answer, according to me it should work from top order.